# ScreenSpace canvas not working

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, render

I am upgrading the UI of my program (from the old Unity UI system to the new one), but it seems like I cannot work with screen-space canvas (either camera or overlay canvases). Objects in world-space canvases work fine. With screen-space GameObjects show in my "Game" preview-screen in the editor, so I am a bit confused as to what the problem may be. To be clear: objects show in the "Game" screen, but not when I press the "play" button.

I attach a composite screenshot with information about one of the objects, the canvases and the camera.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem if everything works at runtime?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Perhaps I did not explain it correctly: it works fine in the "game" preview of the editor, but not when I actually run the program. (Which is why I am at a loss, if the preview did not work either it would be easier.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I now understand what the problem is. Apparently screen-space canvases (either overlay or camera) can ONLY work with UI-specific game objects. I still do not know why other sorts of elements can be added as children of these canvases (and specially why they correctly show in the Game-preview screen!)

Even if I am missing something deeper here, using elements from the UI folder works where others don't. I thought perhaps someone could find that useful.